# selenium how to select/ refer to the current testing webpage

Tags: javascript, selenium, firefox-addon

I am using selenium firefox add-on to write test case.

I use the following command to display the webpage that I test.

- Command: open
- Target: http://aaa.com
- Value:

Then after "http://aaa.com" (test page) is successfully loaded and displayed in my browser.

Say, I know there is a "form" element which has an id of "webform" and it has a unwanted attribute "target" that I want to remove.

In a developer console, I would likely run the following javascript to remove the attribute:
document.findByElementId('webform').removeAttribute('target')

I wonder how to achieve the same thing in selenium add-on? 
how do I refer to the page I am testing?
 (it seems "document.findByElementId" result in an exception:
[error] Threw an exception: document.findByElementId is not a function)

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.
For everybody's posterior reference, this can be achieved by using the following trick:

- Command: getEval
- Target: this.page().findElement('id=webform').removeAttribute('target')
- Value:

Comment: Might be it was a misnomer, just for lack of a better word. :)